# App stalls - no crash, no error

Tags: iphone, crash

It is worth noting that this part of the app (this option from the main menu) was working perfectly before. I then programmed the next option from the main menu, and now this one is not working anymore.

I know the code I've written works, but there is something wrong with either the class or the xib, because it worked when I switched it to call a different class/xib from:

```
UIViewController *nextController = [[OneMethodController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneMethodController" bundle:nil];
```

to:

```
UIViewController *nextController = [[SecondMethodController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondMethodController" bundle:nil];
```

When I try to load the first class/xib (which used to work, as I said), **the app just stalls indefinitely. There is no error and the app does not crash.**

Any ideas?  THANKS!!

Comment: We would probably need to know what's in the initialisation functions of OneMethodController and what's in it's nib to be able to help.

Comment: THANK YOU cool_me5000! What a huge "brain fart" I had, as my dad would say. I can't believe I didn't think to NSLog the viewDidLoad of the class I was trying to open. Once I was able to track down the issue within the viewDidLoad, it was a simple fix. I was asking an array to give me 990 values when it only had 989. Thanks for responding and bringing me out of my daze.  ^_^

Comment: Post  @cool_me5000's answer as a Community Wiki answer, so you can mark is as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the XIB but with the viewDidLoad of that XIB's class. Thanks @cool_me5000 for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that *nextController should most likely be initialized as

SecondMethodController *nextController = [[SecondMethodController alloc] init . . .

And not as

UIViewController *nextController = [[SecondMethodController alloc] init . . .